# Differences between a LM317AHVT and a LM317T

Tags: led, constant-current, lm317

Is there any practical difference between the LM317AHVT and LM317T *vis-a-vis* regulating a 900mA, 9-12V LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "HV" stands for 'high voltage'. If you look at the datasheets you'll see the main difference is the maximum voltage across the regulator (60V for the HV vs. 40V).

Comment: Thanks! I did look at the datasheet, but I interpreted that as the "maximum supported voltage" and hence no difference for the LED in question. Do you know what the `A` stands for?

Comment: Usually A is for a tighter spec or extended temperature range.

Comment: Sometimes the A is used to represent a new design release of the part by the manufacturer. That could have been done to move an older part to a newer semiconductor process or to introduce a part with some of its characteristics changed. Maybe even including a "tighter spec or extended temp" as Spehro has suggested.